# Unable to sent wp_mail on post trash

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am unable to send wp_mail when posts are sent to trash. Below is the function I am using. If anyone could help.

```
    function post_rejection_email() {

            //Email Setup
            $post_status = get_post_meta( the_ID(), 'post_status', true );
            $post_name = $post->post_title;

            //Email Details
            $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' );
            $author_name = the_author_meta('first_name');
            $subject = 'Sorry, your post has been refused.';
            $post_type = 'event_listing';

            $message = 'Dear ' . $author_name . '. Unfortunately your post: ' . $post_name . ' has been refused.';

            if ($post_status == 'trash' && $post->post_type == $post_type) {        
                    wp_mail($email, $subject, $message); 
            }
    }
    add_action('transition_post_status', 'post_rejection_email', 10, 3);
```

I am getting no email. Don't know where I am wrong. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that your code enter the IF-statement?

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out. Is their anything which I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think its not getting the 'trash' status.. I have another function with different status and that one is working fine.. Only with post_status = 'trash' its not doing anything..

Answer (score 0):

I work with Wordpress a little. It looks like the email is being sent to the author of the post that is being sent to the trash, not you (unless you are testing this as the author of the deleted post and it's not working).

If you also wanted to be notified of this apart from the author of the post, try adding a new mail function below that one...

```
wp_mail($email, $subject, $message); 
wp_mail('youremail@example.com', $subject, $message);
```

If it's just not working at all regardless, then there is a problem with your Wordpress installation's email functionality. More information and examples of how the wp_mail function works (including how to configure things like SMTP mail) can be found here: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: When I use wp_mail('my@email.com','test subject','test message'); its working fine. Also I have the access to the author account. No email is sent when I use the variables inside the wp_mail(); else it's working fine. I have another function for different post status which is also working fine. Only with post_status == 'trash' its not sending anything. Dont know whats the issue.